# What information is visible to a packet sniffer which intercepted a HTTPS packet?

Tags: http, https

If I make a HTTPS request to

```
subdomain.example.com/api/login?mytoken=JLK90GFSSFGDS4GFRW0
```

along with uploading a cookie, can a packet sniffer know:

- header information
- subdomain I am requesting
- URL parameters
- cookie contents
- whether it is GZIP compressed

In general, what information is encrypted and what is left plain for a HTTPS packet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything apart from the hostname is encrypted - so in your example the domain name and subdomain are in clear text, everything else is encrypted.

See [Does SSL also encrypt cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195144/does-ssl-also-encrypt-cookies) for more details.

[edited: initial version mistakenly stated that the entire URL was in cleartext. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security makes it quite clear that the server and client first negotiate their encryption, then the application-layer HTTP packets (with the full URL) is sent over this encrypted link.]

Comment: Part of the url is encrypted, '/api/login?mytoken=JLK90GFSSFGDS4GFRW0' is encrypted.

Comment: Does this mean that the typical commercially available VPN is not adding any protection to the content of HTTPS traffic and instead only masking the IP of the client?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of http sniffer do you use.

For example [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) uses a special mode of your network card (by using wincap library) and usually cannot decode https traffic (but you can add your server certificate to wireshark and this will allow wireshark to decode https).

On the other hand, [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com) uses man-in-the-middle technique and can decode **all** https traffic to/from your computer. But you need to manually install HTTP Debugger Pro on your computer under administrator's privileges.

Bellow screenshot of HTTP Debugger decoding HTTPS. 
As you can see, it provides all information about your request/response.

[image: HTTPS Details]