# Sniffing REST API URLs in Mobile App

Tags: android, url, rest, https

I have some HTTPS POST REST API URLs in my mobile app (both Android and iOS) and I was wondering if its possible to sniff those urls?

Comment: Here is a related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195144/does-ssl-also-encrypt-cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The urls CAN be sniffed with package sniffers, on proxy servers, gateways, etc. However, since you're using SSL (and as long as you don't disabled certificate checks), both your post parameters and the responses will be encrypted.