# cookie passing over HTTPS connection

Tags: cookies, https

I read many articles cookies are passed over HTTPS connection is encrypted.
I checked with my application, its having SSL connection, but i can read cookie information from request headers. Is anything done for cookie encryption in HTTPS connection?

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS encrypts the entire session, headers included. 
But notice that SSL (TLS in fact) works over the Transport Layer. If you are reading the cookies from the Application Layer (for example using javascript or a java servlet to get the HTTP request) the content will be already unencrypted.

See [Does SSL also encrypt cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195144/does-ssl-also-encrypt-cookies)