# How do I delete the remember_me cookie when I log out?

Tags: symfony, cookies

I am currently using symfony 5.4 and i wanted to understand how to remove the REMEMBERME server side

I am trying to set the `delete_cookies` parameter in the `security.yaml` under the `logout`:

```
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            switch_user: true
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                secure: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                delete_cookies:
                    REMEMBERME: { path: null, domain: null}
```

but in the same way if with postman I redo a call in a protected route by putting only the REMEMBERME cookie, even without being logged in, it shows me the protected route ... in this way if someone manages to intercept a REMEMBERME of any connected user they can access the system ...

Comment: Install a SSL certificate to prevent cookies from leaking

Comment: @DarkBee Sure? with a simple F12 (development tools) cookies are visible even if there are ssl certificates (therefore domains in https)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195144/does-ssl-also-encrypt-cookies). I mean, if someone has physical access to a device, then no security in the world can help

Comment: If you're that concerned remove the *remember me* functionality all together. It really depends on your app and if your users need to login multiple times per day. Maybe you could reduce the lifetime to 24 hours. Cookie stealing is a thing usually done with users clicking malicious links...

Comment: @Bossman yes, but it seems strange to me not to be able to completely remove the REMEMBERME when the user voluntarily performs the Logout function no?

Comment: @Nobady, it should invalidate the session, yes. Try removing the delete_cookies from the logout and in your access_control add your path (change path to whatever you need to restrict) `- { path: '^/admin', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED] }`

Comment: @Bossman I tried as you suggested, with the route - {path: '^ / logout', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED]}
but in the same way I can get the REMEMBERME before logging out and then I can use it to recall the protected routes ... very strange as a thing

Comment: @Nobady, There are 2 ways remember me cookies can work. Signature based (default, what you have now) and Persistent that stores tokens in the database. You should look at using the Persistent version ([docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#customize-how-remember-me-tokens-are-stored)). This way you can control invalidating the token when logging out.

Comment: @Nobady, also looking at the docs, using the signature based cookies like you have now, you may be able to do something like `signature_properties: ['password', 'updatedAt', 'customField']` add a custom field to your User Entity ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#using-signed-remember-me-tokens)). When logging out just change this field and it will invalidate. This way you don't have to have a database... Something to consider :)

Comment: @Bossman perfect Bossman, with both options you have exposed it finally resolves! Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice one, i posted an answer reflecting this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways *Remember Me* Cookies can work. See the [Symfony docs for token storage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#customize-how-remember-me-tokens-are-stored)

1. **Signature based tokens** By default, the remember me cookie contains a signature based on properties of the user. If the properties change, the signature changes and already generated tokens are no longer considered valid.
2. **Persistent tokens** Persistent tokens store any generated token (e.g. in a database). This allows you to invalidate tokens by changing the rows in the database.

**Persistent tokens** are probably more secure as you can invalidate the tokens via the database at any time you like. In your case you can invalidate the token on logout.

However, you can still invalidate **Signature based tokens** by using **signature_properties** under your *remember_me* firewall.

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            # ...
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                # ...
                signature_properties: ['password', 'updatedAt']
```

You could for example create a new field in your User Entity eg. `rememberMeKey` generating a random 16 digit code for example.

```
bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
```

Then add it to the signature_properties like this `signature_properties: ['password', 'updatedAt', 'rememberMeKey']`.

Now when you would like to invalidate it you can just re-generate a new code for that property in your User Entity, in your case when the user logs out.