# Laravel 8 : Is there any good to use the EncryptCookies middleware if the website is HTTPS?

Tags: laravel, cookies, https

Laravel 8 has an `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` middleware that I am wondering whether it is needed in my case.

httpd port setting is done to ensure only HTTPS is allowed for my site.

Based on this question, [Does SSL also encrypt cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195144/does-ssl-also-encrypt-cookies), it seems HTTPS already encrypts everything including cookies.

Therefore my assumption is that there should be no need to enable EncryptCookies middleware in Laravel 8.

I am just not really sure about are the above assumptions I am making correct or not?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140401/https-and-encrypted-cookie-for-session

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are benefits to encrypting cookies. Maybe you have some data, e.g. some personal info, user id... that you wish to keep private. Even if you only have session id in the cookie you want that to be private.

Cookies can be read manually in a browser or by some javascript. That data can be used to hack sessions or just to get data that is not supposed to be seen by users.

I never encounter any problems in development or production caused by EncryptCookies middleware or even encrypted cookie itself.

If you use free and default Laravel middleware "EncryptCookies", you are ensuring that data from the cookie, including session id, is kept secure and private.